# How do i make try catch stay in try catch

Tags: c#, while-loop, try-catch, console-application

When I write someting like "tre" instead of an integer the try catch writes out but then it continues to while loop. How do I make it stay in try catch when i write someting that is not an integer?

```
    private static double FahrToCels(int f)
    {
        double fahrenheit = f;
        double celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
        return celsius;
    }


    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int fahrenheit = 0;
        double celsius = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Hej och välkommen till bastun!");


        Console.Write("Skriv in en temperatur i Fahrenheit: ");
        try
        {
            fahrenheit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//Användaren skriver in ett värde som lagras i Fahrenheit
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ogiltig inmatning! Ange temperaturen i heltal: ");
        }
        celsius = FahrToCels(fahrenheit);//I variabeln celsius finns antal grader omvandlat från Fahrenheit till Celsius
        celsius = Math.Round(celsius, 0);


        while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77)
        {
            if (celsius < 73)//Om användaren anger en för låg temperatur sker det inom måsvingarna
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för låg!");
                Console.Write("Ange en högre temperatur: ");
                fahrenheit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//Användaren får skriva in ett nytt värde som sparas i variabeln fahrenheit
                celsius = FahrToCels(fahrenheit);//I variabeln celsius finns antal grader omvandlat från Fahrenheit till Celsius
                celsius = Math.Round(celsius, 0);
            }
            else if (celsius > 77)//Om användaren anger en för hög temperatur sker det inom måsvingarna
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Temperaturen är för hög!");
                Console.Write("Ange en lägre temperatur: ");
                fahrenheit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//Användaren får skriva in ett nytt värde som sparas i variabeln fahrenheit
                celsius = FahrToCels(fahrenheit);//I variabeln celsius finns antal grader omvandlat från Fahrenheit till Celsius
                celsius = Math.Round(celsius, 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not use a loop around the try..catch and exit it once a valid input has been detected?

Comment: Also why not use `int.TryParse` then no exception is thrown, you just check the result.

Comment: By “stay in the try catch” do you mean you want to repeat that operation?  Repeating something would be what a loop is for.  Have you tried wrapping your operation(s) in a loop to repeat it?

Comment: i have tried to put "try" in a do-loop but it still goes to if (celsius < 73) after it has done one iteration in the try-block.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to *keep asking* user until a valid integer is given. You can do it in a *loop*:

```
private static int ReadFahrenheit() {
  while (true) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please, provide temperature in Fahrenheit");

    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int result))
      Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer, please, try again");
    else if (result < -459)
      Console.WriteLine("Not a valid value, please, try again");
    else
      return result; 
  }
}
```

Then you can use it as simple as

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int fahrenheit = ReadFahrenheit();
    ...
```